# HTML/CSS Getting the correct order of a button and text and other formatting within a table

Tags: html, css

For the table

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe table table-sm table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>Name <a class="buttonautowidth" style="float:left;"
    onclick="myFunction()" >Hide/Un-hide</a></th>
...
```

[image]

1. I would like 'Name' to be followed by a few spaces, then for the button to be placed.
2. I would like the button font to be normal (**not** bold - not following the `<th>`)

css:

```
.buttonautowidth {
  font-family: Jost;
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 39px;
  background: #1E7F9F;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: white;
}
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use float. Wrap the "text" in a span and let display: inline layout the elements.

Use font-weight to control the button text.

```
 <table border="1" class="dataframe table table-sm table-hover">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <span margin-right="4px">Name<span>
          <a class="buttonautowidth" onclick="myFunction()" >Hide/Un-hide</a>
        </th>
    </table>

.buttonautowidth {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: Jost;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 39px;
  background: #1E7F9F;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lowkase, the only thing that isn't working is the color:white; from the css. Though it does pick it up if style="color:white;" is added to the <a> tag

Comment: Somewhere in your CSS it is probably specifying a color attribute other then white, probably on the TD element. Placing color:white in a style attribute will force specificity and will turn the button color white.  Alternatively, you use "color:white !important" in the ".buttonautowidth" CSS.

Comment: I'm very new to dabbling with direct HMTL/CSS, and have found this "!important" stuff very strange! "Don't override me unless I mark it important" - what a bizarre language - I'm surprised there's not an option for very-important or super-important or even uber-important :]

Comment: hehe, it's mostly used in desperation when all other attempts fail. Gaining a better understanding of "Specificity" in CSS (aka - the Cascade part of CSS) will clarify a lot of your misunderstandings. Try this article to start: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/.

Answer (score 0):

In your markup, the text comes after the button, which is why it is displayed this way. Place the button after the text, and place as many `&nbsp;` characters as you want in between them. Then, use `font-weight:normal` instead of `font-style` (which is used for making text italic/oblique).

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe table table-sm table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th><a class="buttonautowidth" style="float:left;"
    onclick="myFunction()" >Hide/Un-hide</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; Name</th>
...
```